# Select all Tables in power point slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to create a macro which selects all the tables present in a slide in ppt using vba i tried but the macro is selecting the last table or the table created lastly

here is the code

```
Sub CheckCoOrdinates()

    Dim pptPres As Presentation
    Set pptPres = Application.ActivePresentation
    
    Dim pptSlide As Slide
    Dim pptShapes As Shape

    For Each pptSlide In pptPres.Slides
        For Each pptShapes In pptSlide.Shapes
            If pptShapes.Type = msoTable Then
                Dim i As Integer
                For i = 1 To pptSlide.Shapes.Count
                    pptShapes.Select
                    pptShapes.Copy
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

how to create a macro for this

Comment: As far as I know, vba cannot select multiple tables at one time, however we can add the code which pastes to destination in the same loop. Could you please let us know what you want to do with the copied data.

Comment: @  Emmanuel Donald     I want to copy the tables or data from the tables from a **ppt** and paste it into a active excel spread sheet

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pptShapes.Select, use pptShapes.Select (False)

The default behavior of Select mimics clicking on a new shape ... the clicked shape is selected, replacing any previous selection.  Adding the False parameter makes it behave more like Ctrl+clicking ... the newly selected shape is ADDED to the current selection.

That'll work on a per slide basis but you can't select shapes on multiple slides, so you're going to have to re-write your macro accordingly.

I suspect you'll be better off stepping through each slide, then through each shape on the slide and copy/pasting the tables one at a time.